# Writing a recursive javascript algorithm to find a specific object type

Tags: javascript

Essentially, I'm testing a hierarcy treeview dataset to see if there exists any object which is considered a `Host` node; meaning, it simply has properties `HostID` and `HostName`.

If I find just one `Host` node, I return true - and I'm done.

However, I'm not getting an accurate `true/false` return value in this recursive routine below. i.e. I get an inaccurate false return values sometimes.

```js
hasChildHosts_2(tree: any) {
  if (tree.subs !== null && tree.subs.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.subs.length; i++) {
      if (tree.subs[i].HostID != null && tree.subs[i].HostName != null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (tree.subs[i].subs !== undefined) {
        this.hasChildHosts_2(tree.subs[i]);
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

a small sample set as follows: a `Location` node contains a `subs` array - which contains a `Location` node and two `Host` nodes. And of course I always know a Location by the `LocationName` prop and a Host by the `HostID` prop :

```html
{ "UID":2,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Bergen County","ParentLocation":null, "subs":[ {"UID":42,"GUID":"","LocationName":"yy","Description":"","subs":[ {"UID":3,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Essex County","ParentLocation":null} {"HostID":100,"HostName":"MYHOST100","HostIP":"10.1.1.12"},
{"HostID":200,"HostName":"MYHOST200","HostIP":"10.1.1.19"} ] ] } }
```

Please review for accuracy. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I just took a quick glance, but wouldn't you want to `return` the value of line 8? The way it is now, you're always going to get `false` unless the `if` check on line 4 passes on the first time you call the function.

Comment: id also watch out for `!= null` too - if you could post up a working example snippet I could definitively give you an answer

Comment: You didn't returns the result of the recursive call to hasChildHosts_2

Comment: Please create a [mcve] instead of non-running snippets

Comment: The second parameter of `JSON.parse` can be used to check all of the values of you are parsing the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented your code on a sample codepen. As pointed on comments, you need to return the result of the recursive function. Furthemore, the tree is an invalid JSON, I've fixed it:

```js
var globalTree = {
  UID: 2,
  GUID: "",
  LocationName: "Bergen County",
  ParentLocation: null,
  subs: [{
    UID: 42,
    GUID: "",
    LocationName: "yy",
    Description: "",
    subs: [{
        UID: 3,
        GUID: "",
        LocationName: "Essex County",
        ParentLocation: null
      },
      {
        HostID: 100,
        HostName: "MYHOST100",
        HostIP: "10.1.1.12"
      },
      {
        HostID: 200,
        HostName: "MYHOST200",
        HostIP: "10.1.1.19"
      }
    ]
  }]
};

var hasChildHosts_2 = function(tree) {
  if (tree.subs !== null && tree.subs.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.subs.length; i++) {
      if (tree.subs[i].HostID != null && tree.subs[i].HostName != null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (tree.subs[i].subs !== undefined) {
        return hasChildHosts_2(tree.subs[i]);
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log("result: " + hasChildHosts_2(globalTree));
```

Comment: Indeed you're right. I missed the return. Also, apologies for the non-running script as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply check each item and recurse on `subs` if it's an array:

```js
let obj = {"UID":2,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Bergen County","ParentLocation":null,"subs":[{"UID":42,"GUID":"","LocationName":"yy","Description":"","subs":[{"UID":3,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Essex County","ParentLocation":null},{"HostID":100,"HostName":"MYHOST00","HostIP":"10.1.1.12"},{"HostID":200,"HostName":"MYHOST00","HostIP":"10.1.1.19"}]}]}

let obj_no_host = {"UID":2,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Bergen County","ParentLocation":null,"subs":[{"UID":42,"GUID":"","LocationName":"yy","Description":"","subs":[{"UID":3,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Essex County","ParentLocation":null},{"HostID":100},{"HostID":200}]}]}

function test(o){   
    for (item of o) {
        if (item.HostName !== undefined && item.HostIP !== undefined) return true
        if (Array.isArray(item.subs)) return test(item.subs)
    }
   return false

}
console.log("With host -- ", test([obj]))
console.log("Without host -- ", test([obj_no_host]))
```

Comment: that looks really tight and efficient. I'll try it.